# Ticking/ rattling noise when foot on brake

Tags: honda, noise, accord

I have a 2004 Honda Accord EX. When I am stepping on the brakes it rattles extremely loud. At lights it’s extremely loud. I’ve found that putting my car in "N" or park while at the light it will silence the sound until I put it back in "D". Can someone help me diagnose what the problem might be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that you have a loose heat shield on your exhaust. When in gear the rpm's are lower which causes more engine vibration. Also these vibrations can be amplified by a vacuum leak, engine misfire or worn motor mounts.

Comment: thank you so much, i’ll find a mechanic to take a look with the information you provided me :)